# Fill an array with nan in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy vector my_indexes of size **1XN** which contain boolean values of indexing and a 2D array my_array of size **MxK** where K << N. Actually, the boolean vector correspond to columns that I remove (or keep in the array my_array) and I want to add those columns back filled with zeros (or 'NaNs'). My code for removing the columns:

```
 my_array= np.array(my_array[:, ~np.all(np.isnan(my_array), axis=0)])
 cols = np.all(np.isnan(my_array), axis=0)
 my_array = some_process(my_array)
 # How can I add the removed columns
```

My array if of size **MXN** and then the size is **MXK**. How can I fill the removed columns again with nan or zeros?

An example could be:

```
0.1 nan 0.3 .04 nan 0.12 0.12
0.1 nan 0.3 .04 nan 0.12 0.12
0.1 nan 0.3 .04 nan 0.12 0.12
```

Firstly, I want to remove the nan columns using `my_array= np.array(my_array[:, ~np.all(np.isnan(my_array), axis=0)])`.

```
0.1 0.3 .04 0.12 0.12
0.1 0.3 .04 0.12 0.12
0.1 0.3 .04 0.12 0.12
```

And the my_indexes vector is:

```
False True False False True False False
```

Then I want to process the matrix and then have the nan columns back (note that the preprocessing cannot happened with the nan columns). I guess that I need to use the [np.insert function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) however how can I do so using my boolean vector

Comment: Instead of removing them to begin with, just replace their values with NaN. I don't get why you remove them if you do not want to?

Comment: This is very confusing. Can you give an *example* of an input array, what you are doing currently, what you want as desired output? It helps to *show* us, if possible, instead of describe.

Comment: Check my edit .

Comment: myarray[index_vector]= 0, if you already have your booelan vector, you can use it to select those values

Comment: Yes but my_array has smaller size from index_vector (numper of cols). Can I really do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably use [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) for that:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

def some_process(x):
    return x**2

x = np.arange(9, dtype=float).reshape(3, 3)
x[:,1] = np.nan
print(x)
# [[  0.  nan   2.]
#  [  3.  nan   5.]
#  [  6.  nan   8.]]

# mask all np.nan and np.inf
masked_x = ma.masked_invalid(x)
# Compute the process only on the unmasked values and fill back np.nan
x = ma.filled(some_process(masked_x), np.nan)
print(x)
# [[  0.  nan   4.]
#  [  9.  nan  25.]
#  [ 36.  nan  64.]]
```

Comment: Really smooth solution thanks. However, is there a way to do the same using my vector indexes? I also want to know the indexes of the removed columns since I use them later.

Comment: @konstantin  `masked_x.mask` contains the mask used by the masked array. If you need the indices, just call `np.where(masked_x.mask)` on it.

Comment: Can I apply that in another matrix or vector with the same size of cols, the result of the np.where(masked_x.mask) ?